# @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import not working in imported node module

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

I have `["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]` in my `.babelrc` file, and I am successfully able to use dynamic imports on Vue files that are in my own project, but when trying to import a node/npm module with `import App from '@something/app';` I get this error when building with Webpack:

```
SyntaxError: \node_modules\@something\app\src\SomeApp.vue: Support for the experimental syntax 'dynamicImport' isn't currently enabled (16:19):

  14 |  name: 'SomeApp',
  15 |  components: {
> 16 |      SomeCompontent: () => import('./some-dir/SomeCompontent.vue'),
     |                      ^


Add @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import (https://git.io/vb4Sv) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing.
```

`@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` is enabled as plugin in my project and the node module being imported, but Babel just isn't respecting that for some reason.

Is there anything extra I need to do to be able to make Babel apply this plugin when importing a node module?

Thanks

Comment: So I am able to work around the issue by copying the contents of the node module to my own project and deleting the package.json, if package.json is there it doesn't work...

Comment: it is just the package.json file being there, even if it is just empty.

Comment: OK so this is apparently the expected behaviour for .babelrc, just trying to work around it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So as I wrote in the comments, this is expected behaviour in Babel.
But solving it isn't super straight forward so I am logging how to do so in case anyone else ever needs it.

You need to use `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc`, this is a more *global* configuration method. Docs are here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration
Really though it is can be as simple as copy and pasting your `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and adding `module.exports =`  before the object.

Once you are applying Babel to your `node_modules` you are going to create different issues. You need to prevent Babel from Babelling itself and `core-js`. This is prevented by adding `ignore: [/[\/\\]core-js/, /@babel[\/\\]runtime/]` to your `babel.config.js`.

And then finally you need to prevent Babel from messing up your exports since you can't mix usage of `modules.exports` and `export default`. This fix seems a little hacky to me, but ¯\*(ツ)*/¯. The last thing we need to do is add `'sourceType': 'unambiguous'` also to your `babel.config.js`.

The steps above so far are working perfectly for me, if I discover any other road bumps I'll be sure to update this answer.